# Why are my radio options behaving this way in jQuery form validation?

Tags: html, jquery, validation, radio-button

I used the following code(below) for the radio menu, the form submits successfully if i don't check any of the boxes BUT If i check an option and then click submit, the 'Select one' error will show.. It's doing the opposite of what i need it to; Any feedback would be greatly appreciated mate - thanks:

HTML:

```
<div>
<label for="contact_radio" <="" label="">
<input type="radio" id="contact_radio" name="radio">Keen to join</input>
<label for="contact_radio" <="" label="">
<input type="radio" id="contact_radio" name="radio">Already a member</input>
Select one
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[name="radio"]').on('change', function() {
var selected_input=$('input[name="radio"]:checked');
var is_myradio=re.test(input.val());
if(is_myradio){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
});
```

Comment: What's going on with the `<=""` before the label?

Comment: What is input in input.val() ?

Comment: What is `re`. Is that regular expression defined somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

None of your radio inputs have value attributes, so you'll need to add these. You shouldn't be duplicating I'd attributes either, but that's not causing your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

What is input in input.val() ? Your if condition is checking the value of input, comparing it with regex and adding class accordingly. Not according to whether you have selected item or not 
 Use this instead :

```
$('input[name="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    var input = $('#your_input');
    var selected_input=$("input[name='name']).is(":checked");
    var is_input_validated=re.test(input.val());
    if(is_input_validated && selected_input) {
        input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    }
    else{
        input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks dude, i should note that i'm an absolute novice with jQuery, so please bare with me ..what would be an example of the input('#your_input')

Comment: In your line `var is_myradio=re.test(input.val());`, you are comparing a variable named input with a regex(re). So I assumed your form is having an input box named say `my_inputbox`. So you will access its value using selector `$('[name="my_inputbox"]').val()` if you want to compare it with a regex

Comment: thanks mrid, hmm it doesn't seem to be working - is there any chance i can email/dropbox you my working files? thanks heaps for your time so far

Comment: Sure, you can drop me a mail at mridul.ahuja@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 // Name can't be blank
$('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
 var input=$(this);
 var re = /^.{2,}$/;
 var is_name=re.test(input.val());
 if(is_name){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
 else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}

});

// Phone number must be more than 2 digits
$('#contact_phone').on('input', function() {
 var input=$(this);
 var re = /^.{2,}$/;
 var is_phone=re.test(input.val());
 if(is_phone){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
 else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}

});

// Email must be an email
$('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
 var input=$(this);
 var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
 var is_email=re.test(input.val());
 if(is_email){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
 else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
});

// Message can't be blank
$('#contact_message').keyup(function(event) {
 var input=$(this);
 var message=$(this).val();
 console.log(message);
 if(message){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
 else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");} 
});

// Must select an age
$('input[name="contact_age"]').on('change', function() {
    var input = $('#contact_age');
    var selected_input=$("input[name='select']").is(":checked");
    var is_input_validated=re.test(input.val());
    if(is_input_validated && selected_input) {
        input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    }
    else{
        input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
});


// Must click a check box
$('input[name="radio"]').on('change', function() {
 /* >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> */
 /*  removed the entire validation from here since 
        once one radio button is selected, a button in
        the button group will always be selected and can't
        be un selected, so no point validating
 */
    $(this).parents('div').find('.error').hide();
});


// After Form Submitted Validation
$("#contact_submit button").click(function(event){
 var form_data=$("#contact").serializeArray();
 var error_free=true;
 for (var input in form_data){
  var element=$("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
  var valid=element.hasClass("valid");
  var error_element=$("span", element.parent());
  if (!valid){error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show"); error_free=false;}
  else{error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");}
 }
 if(!$("input[name='radio']").is(":checked")){
  $("input[name='radio']").parents('div').find('.error').show();
 }


 if (!error_free){
  event.preventDefault(); 
 }
 else{
  alert('Form submitted!');
 }
});


});
```

```css
html {
    background-image: url("images/footballField.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: arial;
}
#contact {
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 900px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 600px;
}
#contact label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#contact_submit {
    padding-left: 100px;
}
#contact div {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
#select {
    font-size: 14px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
textarea {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 5em;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-color: lightgray;
}
.error {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.error_show {
    color: red;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 9px;
}
input.invalid,
textarea.invalid {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
input.valid,
textarea.valid {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
#form {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact" method="post" action="">
    <!-- Name -->
    <div>
        <label for="contact_name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name"></input>
        <span class="error">Your name is required</span>
    </div>
    <!--Phone -->
    <div>
        <label for="contact_phone">Phone:</label>
        <input type="phone" id="contact_phone" name="phone"></input>
        <span class="error">A valid number is required</span>        
    </div>
    <!-- Email -->
    <div>
        <label for="contact_email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="email"></input>
        <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>    
    </div>
    <!-- Age Group -->
    <div>
        <label for="contact_age"</label>
        <tr>
            <td>Age group:&emsp;
        </tr>
        <td>
            <select name="Age groups" >
                <option value="select"></option>
                <option value="2">Adults</option>
                <option value="3" >U12's</option>
                <option value="4" >U6's</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        </td></tr></p>
    </div>
    <!-- Member intentions -->
    <div>
        <!-- >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> CORRECTED YOUR LABELS -->
        <label for="contact_radio1"><input type="radio" id="contact_radio1" name="radio">Keen to join Oaktown FC</input></label>
        <label for="contact_radio2"><input type="radio" id="contact_radio2" name="radio">Already a member</input></label>
        <span class="error">Select one</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Message -->
    <div>
        <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="contact_message" name="message"></textarea>
        <span class="error">This field is required</span>            
    </div>
    <!-- Submit Button -->
    <div id="contact_submit">    
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```